# git rebase fixup after push is rejected

Tags: git, github, rebase

I have pushed a feature branch to github that I realized I want to rebase in order to squash some commits.  I run

```
git rebase HEAD~5
```

on my local branch and set all but the first and last commit to "fixup". I save and quit and the rebase continues fine. When I try to push I get

```
 error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:username/repo.git'
 hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
 hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
 hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

Is there a way to do this without push -f or is that my only recourse? Is there a better way to squash the commits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way is with `git push -f`.  The commits you removed (by replacing them with a single squashed one) are already on the remote.  Without `-f`, you can only add commits, not remove/replace them.

On the other hand, if nobody has `pull`ed yet, it shouldn't be a problem.